# HTML5 Canvas - Get textbox value in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Here's my JSFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/fknjz/5/

(forget about the SAVE button next to the UPDATE button...)

So what I would like is to be able to fill the textboxes that are below the main image, and that when pressing "UPDATE button"....the text would update in the Canvas.

The JS code is in the HTML section...It wasn't working well when it was in the JS section.

Right now I tried :

```
<input type="text" id="nom"/>  /* THE TEXTBOX */
```

and for the JS code to draw the text :

```
oCtx.fillText(document.getElementById("nom").value, 283, 350);
```

It's not working very well...since nothing happens when I click on UPDATE...
With FIREFOX it seems to be working with a window.refresh...but not working in Chrome, Safari...etc. What function would make it work correctly in major browsers?

Thank you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/fknjz/12/ this will not work in the fiddle (saving) because security issues... however this works. I have re-written this to make a bit more sense... hopefully my changes are understood by you.

Comment: I only re-wrote it because fixing it would not help you any. your flow and everything was kinda messed up. also inline js in HTML < ... onclick=... /> is generally to be avoided.. separation of code and concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have imported everything in Dreamweaver, but it's not working. The background-image is not showing at all. I tried it in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, and nothings working.?

Comment: I would suggest you avoid using DreamWeaver 'design mode' - your HTML is malformed.. looks like a DW generated HTML. - in fact I suggest you avoid DW all together... having been a long time DW user myself - I can say i'm much more productive now that I am not using it. notepad++, geany, sublime text 2 are all nice alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I will check these apps out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fknjz/17/

I moved the code for writing the text in canvas to a function called 'updateClicked'. On click of update button, this function will get called. Moreover, I made 'oCtx' a global variable.
Now working fine.

Comment: Oh...I just found out that if I change the text and click UPDATE again, it will ADD the modified text over what I typed before...How can I make it always change the text for what's in the textbox, instead of adding line of text over each other? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should put inside a "onclick" function, not on "onload. But, then again, i'm also new to all this!

I hope this will help you.

---

OR, try this:

**oCtx.fillText("document.getElementById("nom").value", 283, 350);**

(note the quotes)

---

Best Regards,
Tiago

Comment: When I put the quotes, it seems to be working. Look: http://i.imgur.com/Pia9z.jpg"

Comment: But the UPDATE button needs a function, what would it be? That's what I can't manage to find

Comment: Oh, you are using Firefox, aren't you? I tried in firefox and it's already working the way I did it. That's the thing, the way I built it is not working well since it's only working in Firefox. I need the right code and function to update the Canvas image with the textbox value using the UPDATE button in a way it will work correctly with all major browsers (at least Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE9). Thanks!

Comment: I see, have you tried the <!DOCTYPE html>, this is the default HTML5 doctype.